# JavaFX 8 Problems with FXML loading as stage

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to load my FXML file as stage in JavaFX 8.
Here is my **updated** code

```
Stage window;
private AnchorPane GuiStage;

    public void showMainView() throws IOException
    {
    try{
       FXMLLoader loader = new   MLLoader(MyViewPart.class.getResource("/bthesis/views/test.fxml"));
       AnchorPane GuiStage = loader.load();
       Scene s1 = new Scene(GuiStage);
       window.setScene(s1);
       window.show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
```

Full patch to my FXML file is

```
C:\Users\Łukasz\workspace\BThesis\src\bthesis\views\test.fxml
```

Package name

```
bthesis.views
```

I added fx:controller to my FXML file now I got null pointer error. Full error trace.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bthesis.MyViewPart.showMainView(MyViewPart.java:67)
    at bthesis.MyViewPart.start(MyViewPart.java:102)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application bthesis.MyViewPart
```

Comment: Should be `MyViewPart.class.getResource("/bthesis/views/test.fxml")`. Furthermore you have to make sure it's actually included in the classpath when running the application.

Comment: Added my fxml file to build patch, but now my Eclipse tells me that I have en error, dont says which. I just cant start my program

Comment: Is your window variable being initialized? If this is happening at ` window.setScene(s1);` I bet it's because you're not initializing that variable

Comment: @SamOrozco Wow, thanks a lot friend. Now it,s working fine.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your path like this while using **setLocation** method

```
 loader.setLocation(MyViewPart.class.getResource("views/test.fxml"));
```

if this doesn't help. create a java class e.g. **Helper** in views package then use its reference as

```
  loader.setLocation(Helper.class.getResource("test.fxml"));
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confusion to set path.
I explain.

```
If you project directory structure is like

    src
    .
    .
    .----bthesis
         .
         .
         .------views
                .
                .
                .test.fxml
```

Then you have to set location path just like this.

```
loader.setLocation(MyViewPart.class.getResource("/bthesis/views/test.fxml"));
```

Comment: I am using AnchorPane FXML file type. And I am doing something like this `GuiStage = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(MyViewPart.class.getResource("/bthesis/views/test.fxml"));` Still dont know how to solve this, Your code doesnt work too my friend :(

Comment: I eddited post another time

Comment: So I went to the SceneBuilder and set proper controller class for the FXML file. And now I get null pointer excpetion error.